How to remove options menu completely from one of the fragments
Previously I was using simple setHasOptionsMenu(false); in onCreateView and it worked as expected. Now, that setHasOptionsMenu is deprecated, it's unclear how to hide options menu altogether while the fragment is shown.
I considered doing
MenuHost parent = (MenuHost) requireActivity();
parent.removeMenuProvider((MenuProvider) parent);

but it looks wrong.
Or should I make my fragment MenuProvider and then clear the menu?
public void onCreateMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater inflater) {
    menu.clear();
}

Which will probably work but looks excessively verbose for such a simple thing.
